# Mapstruct - update existing bean and ignore a field

Tags: mapstruct

I am updating a bean [according to documentation](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#updating-bean-instances):

```
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {
    void updateCarFromDto(CarDto carDto, @MappingTarget Car car);
}
```

Is it possible to tell mapstruct to ignore a certain field(s) ? F.e. I don't want mapstruct to map `id` field from `carDto` to `car` entity, and that is what mapstruct will do if I don't define the body and skip `id` field mapping manually. 
 If it's not currently possible, is there any workaround (different than own impl.) ?

Comment: What about @Mapping(target="Id", ignore=true)?

Comment: You can use @aftermapping on a method to complete your mapping for id

Comment: (1) You can put that as an answer, as it solves the problem (I will mark it). 
(2) what do you mean by 'You can use @aftermapping on a method to complete your mapping for id' ? You mean that, if I wanted to put an `id` manually, I could still do that by using `@AfterMapping` method, is that correct ?

Comment: That is indeed the idea. Make a default method with the same signature and mark it with the @Aftermapping annotation. Be careful though if the mapping method itself is called from other places. You just created a duplicate. If that's the case you need to use a Qualifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@Mapping( target = "id", ignore = true )`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use (nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
try @Mapping(source = "id", target = "id", ignore = true)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).