# Update an existing bean instance with mapstruct and keep some old fields

Tags: mapstruct

I want to update an existing bean like asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590804/mapstruct-update-existing-bean-and-ignore-a-field).

Using `@Mapping( target = "id", ignore = true )` to keep the old id and only update all the other fields does not work though. The id is still updated. This also applies to using `@BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)` and trying to map each field manually.

My mapping:

```java
@Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
void updateUsersFromDto(List<UserDto> dtos, @MappingTarget List<User> entities);
```

Comment: try to write `map(UserDTO, User)` and `@Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true) update(UserDTO, @MappingTarget User)` and use these methods as base to mapping iterables; it's more similar to linked example that works on single entity and not on lists.

Comment: to map a List of UserDto into a List of User, you probably have a method that map a single UserDto into a User, and MapStruct will use that method to map each UserDto in the list. Probably there is something wrong in this one.

Answer (score 0):

1 - declare a single object mapping method (updateUserFromUserDto)

2 - declare the list of object mapping method that will use the updateUserFromUserDto to update each element of the list (updateUsersFromUsersDto)

This should work:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {
 
    UserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);
    
    @Named("updateUserFromUserDto")
    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    void updateUserFromUserDto(UserDto dto, @MappingTarget User entity);
    
    // I'm not sure if @MappingTarget is required or not here, since it is already present in updateUserFromUserDto
    @IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "updateUserFromUserDto")
    void updateUsersFromUsersDto(List<UserDto> dtos, @MappingTarget List<User> entities);
    
}
```